# Configuring logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to install elasticsearch components and following [those](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash) installation steps

Downloaded and unzipped those:

```
elasticsearch-7.4.0-windows-x86_64
kibana-7.4.0-windows-x86_64
logstash-7.4.0
```

Then created `logstash-simple.conf`

```
input { stdin { } }
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

in `logstash-7.4.0\logstash-7.4.0\bin` and then run this:

```
logstash -f logstash-simple.conf
```

it throws me an error

> "Elasticsearch Unreachable"

I tried to tun this `elasticsearch-7.4.0-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.4.0\bin\elasticsearch.bat` , command prompt opens, it loads something and then command prompt closes automatically, so I'm not sure whether there are errors if any. This doesn't solve above error.

How I can solve above error?

**Off topic**. Why when running elasticsearch.bat it refers to JDK within `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`, and not within `C:\Program Files\Java` . How I can install Java 11 to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`, I was only able to install that to `C:\Program Files\Java`

Answer (score 1):

After long time, I finally figured it out.
The reason it was failing is because it was referring to 32 bit Java version. I just changed `JAVA_HOME` path to 64 bit version, and `elastic search` runs, so does `logstash`